# Making AngularJS form page dirty using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make the AngularJS form field dirty by using JavaScript code,

Here is the HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">

  <p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
  </form>

  <p>The input's valid state is:</p>
  <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried using

```
document.querySelector('input[name="myInput"]').value="123",
```

clicking, focusing but none of them seems to work/override it. Please guide me on how to do that **without** using AngularJS functions and by using plain JavaScript.

I want to change the input's valid state to `true`

Comment: AngularJS IS JavaScript, and it has `.$setDirty()` method that you can use in a controller

Comment: i need to interact with the angular app , without changing the code in angular,  like through chrome console

Comment: You can use jQLite (jQuery) in your console as `angular.element(document)` and add some other functions like `.find()` to it to select your form. Look these functions up in here: [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

To interact with angular App from console you need to use

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourElementId')).scope();
```

this will bring you the required scope, then to set element as dirty you can use

```
scope.myForm.myInput.$setViewValue(scope.myForm.myInput.$viewValue);
```

Comment: it wont work in production version of angular,i need to do it using javascript from console

Comment: what do you mean it wont work in production ?:) .. the above code also will run in console normally.. if i am missing something

Comment: when the angular file is rendered on server , currently i am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined, when i used Augury (Angular Inspector) it was showing the angular app is running in production mode

Comment: @HanyHabib The `.scope()` method requires [Debug Data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) to be enabled. For more information, see [AngularJS `angular.element` API Reference - jQuery/jqLite Extra Methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   var $body = angular.element(document.body);
   var $scope = $body.data().$scope;
   $scope.myForm.myInput.$setDirty();
   $scope.$apply();
```

### The DEMO

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   var $body = angular.element(document.body);
   var $scope = $body.data().$scope;
   $scope.myForm.myInput.$setDirty();
   $scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">

  <p>Watch dirty state flash from false to true</p>

  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
  </form>

  <p>The input dirty state is:</p>
  <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$dirty}}</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i want to perform the same on production version of angular, but anguar.functions wont work on them

Comment: I tested this code with the production version of AngularJS and it works.

Comment: Is there any other way without using angular.fns code , the site which I'm using is not understanding angular.fns code may be they are using server side rendering